# mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_assoc) meaning of fetch

Tags: php

I have Problems understanding this code. What does `fetch` do in php. What does it mean. For what do I Need the resulttype MYSQLI_ASSOC and why do I Need a `mysqli_fetch_array`. Could someone give me a quick Explanation?

```
$row= mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: There is a thing known as database which contains data in ordered manner. MySQL is a type of database. You can fetch the data from database using `mysqli_*` functions.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat and what is fetching?Getting data into an Array or what?

Comment: "Fetching" means to *fetch* (| fɛtʃ | verb [with object] *go for and then bring back (someone or something) for someone*) the data from the database into the PHP script. It causes the actual data to be copied, perhaps across a network.

Answer (score 0):

**mysql_fetch_array**=> Fetch a result row as a **numeric array** and as an **associative array**.

**mysql_fetch_assoc**=> Fetch a result  as an **associative array**.

**mysql_fetch_row**=> Fetches **one row from a result-set** and returns it as an enumerated array

**mysql_fetch_object**=> Returns the current row of a result set, as an **object**

Use this link and you can learn more about. 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp